# How can I populate an array with a current variable and retrieve the prior, not the current, variable from this array all with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I have here is part of a larger project, but I have tried to isolate my current issue by stripping out the rest of the program to just show the current issue. There may be a couple of remnants of other stuff remaining, that in the current setting do not do anything, but are used in the full program.

What I am currently trying to do with what is shown below is as follow:

1/ When I click on a number in the lower display, it should show in the upper display under new number. This does operate fine as it should.

2/ When the next number is clicked on, I would like to see the prior number show up in the prior number section. This does not work.

I am assuming that this can be done by creating a blank array (myARR) with javascript, adding the new value of the next clicked number to the array and then reading the prior number that would then be in the second position of the array?

3/ I would also like to keep a running count of numbers clicked on. Also not working.

I am assuming that this could be accomplished by using the javascript length property on the array.

I think I have a rough idea of the processes (but I may be wrong), but I am having a devil of a time trying to get the coding to work, thank you. The alert window response will not be in the end product, as I am just using it currently to get a response that I can see and work from, but all I am getting is undefined.

Thanking anyone for their assistance,
Stan

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type='text/javascript'
src='jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


</HEAD>
<script type='text/javascript'
src='jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>


<BODY STYLE="background-color: yellow" >


<TABLE width="100%" border="1" >
<TR>

    
<script type="text/javascript">
  function reply_click(clicked_id)
  {
      //alert(clicked_id);
    //document.write(clicked_id);
    document.getElementById("clicked_id").innerHTML = clicked_id;
        
let myARR = clicked_id[12];
    
    //document.write(myArr[0]);
    //var clicked_id = pmARR(2);
    //var myARR = [clicked_id];
    //myARR = clicked_id;
    //var (clicked_id) = pmAAA[];
    
//var clicked_id = myARR[2];
        
//myARR.push(clicked_id);


//console.log(myARR[0,5]);





alert (myARR);


//alert(myARR);

//document.writeln((i+1) + ": " + myARR[i]);


  }
</script>


<TD><CENTER>

<B>



<B>NEW NUMBER</b><BR>


<span style="font-size: 89px" id="clicked_id"></span>


<HR width="100%">


<B>Prior Number</b><BR>




<Script>

console.log(myARR().value);
</script>

<HR width="100%">

<B>How Many Numbers Picked</b><BR>

<SCRIPT>
myARR.length:
</script>

</center>


<FORM NAME="numbers">
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" >



&nbsp;


<P>



<TR><TD COLSPAN="3">
<!-- numbers table -->
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="1" STYLE="background-color: #0080FF; font-size: x-large; font-family: sans-

serif; font-weight: 900; text-align: center" bgcolor=#0080FF>
<TR>

<TD button id="01" onClick="reply_click(this.id);ManualColorBlue(this);" ondblclick="ManualColorBACK(this)"><BIG>1</button>
<TD button id="02" onClick="reply_click(this.id);ManualColorBlue(this);" ondblclick="ManualColorBACK(this)"><BIG>2</button>
<TD button id="03" onClick="reply_click(this.id);ManualColorBlue(this);" ondblclick="ManualColorBACK(this)"><BIG>3</button>
<TD button id="04" onClick="reply_click(this.id);ManualColorBlue(this);" ondblclick="ManualColorBACK(this)"><BIG>4</button>
<TD button id="05" onClick="reply_click(this.id);ManualColorBlue(this);" ondblclick="ManualColorBACK(this)"><BIG>5</button>
<TD button id="06" onClick="reply_click(this.id);ManualColorBlue(this);" ondblclick="ManualColorBACK(this)"><BIG>6</button>
<TD button id="07" onClick="reply_click(this.id);ManualColorBlue(this);" ondblclick="ManualColorBACK(this)"><BIG>7</button>
<TD button id="08" onClick="reply_click(this.id);ManualColorBlue(this);" ondblclick="ManualColorBACK(this)"><BIG>8</button>
<TD button id="09" onClick="reply_click(this.id);ManualColorBlue(this);" ondblclick="ManualColorBACK(this)"><BIG>9</button>
<TD button id="10" onClick="reply_click(this.id);ManualColorBlue(this);" ondblclick="ManualColorBACK(this)"><BIG>10</button>
<TD button id="11" onClick="reply_click(this.id);ManualColorBlue(this);" ondblclick="ManualColorBACK(this)"><BIG>11</button>
<TD button id="12" onClick="reply_click(this.id);ManualColorBlue(this);" ondblclick="ManualColorBACK(this)"><BIG>12</button>



</TD></TR></TABLE>
<!-- end numbers table -->


</TABLE>
</FORM>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Before continuing, please read [how to manipulate documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents), [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) is not the way how you transfer data between JS and HTML. I'd also suggest you to find a newer tutorial, the one you currently use seems to be from '90s.

Comment: Please write your question clear and understandable, not so long.

Comment: Hi @Teemu, Many thanks for your input on using DOM instead of document.write. As far as my tutorial, I try to utilize a lot of what I find right here on stackoverflow, and I try to stick to the newer entries. Thanks again, Stan...

Comment: Hi @Vivekanand Vishvkarma, Sorry if my question appears to be too long, but I included a three part question on basically the same code process, so, a longer question than usually seen here. I included it all in to one pos, instead of cluttering up this board with three separate posts about the the same code. But thanks for your input anyways, Stan...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `let myARR = clicked_id[12];`.

> The let declaration declares a block-scoped local variable, optionally
> initializing it to a value
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

which means myARR will only exist inside your `reply_click` function. Which also means that, when `reply_click` is invoked next, myARR will not exist, and will be recreated from scratch, you need it to persist a little bit more. A solution would be to use `var myARR = clicked_id[12];` outside of `reply_click` function.

> The var statement declares a function-scoped or globally-scoped variable, optionally initializing it to a value.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Other than that, the right side is also wrong, `clicked_id[12]` is meaningless, because `clicked_id` should be a number. Try it in your browser. Enter console by right clicking > inspect, or usually F12 and searching it in the tabs, and typing

```
let clicked_id = 2;
let myARR = clicked_id[12];
```

`myARR` should now be `undefined`. What you actually want is to create an empty array, where we will store all activated numbers, keeping in mind `var` vs `let`.
Inside `reply_click` we will reference it without creating a new variable, and append to it using the `push` method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myARR = []; // new line
  function reply_click(clicked_id)
  {
      //alert(clicked_id);
    //document.write(clicked_id);
    document.getElementById("clicked_id").innerHTML = clicked_id;
        
    myARR.push(clicked_id); // modified line
...
```

I believe your main issue was not remembering that `var` is block-scoped when used inside a function. It needs to be used in top level to become global.

To finish the rest you use `myARR.length` as you said, and `myARR().value` should become something like `myARR[myARR.length - 2]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your point on taking my array  out of the on_click function was pivotal in helping me to resolve my issues today. Most helpful indeed. Many thanks again... Stan...